# Building relationships with HR/ MDs/Heads when job searching

Tags: professionalism, job-search

I'm job searching currently. I keep reading online about many seekers taking a competitive edge by forming relationships with Heads, MDs, HR etc such as going out for coffee or lunch with them, before a position is even open.

Is this standard? Can I ask if anyone here uses that strategy and how they go about it, I would feel so awkward!

Comment: How will you approach these people in the first place?

Comment: I think it normally goes the other way round. You get to known somebody and hit it off well - and later learn he has a job-opportunity for you ...

Comment: It’s common but you wouldn’t ask here if u knew those people. No day dreaming.

Answer (score 1):

The buzzword for this sort of thing is "networking", and it's usefulness varies from industry to industry. Establishing a relationship with a decision maker at a company in your field can certainly help when it comes to applying for jobs but the eternal question with it is how you get to have that initial contact and again this varies from industry to industry.

It generally **doesn't** consist of cold contact but rather meeting these people through industry events and job fairs and the like or through a mutual connection.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing seems to be becoming more and more popular as it's definitely an easy way to get a good start with a company. You can call it many things, but it comes down to good old fashioned ***networking***.

This sort of thing is really useful because it gives you a bit of an edge against those that simply 'cold apply' to positions as the company (*or at least the decision maker*) knows you and how you might be able to fit into the role, whereas it's much more effort involved finding this out from someone new in an interview. They'd already know what you're like from a causal sit down and coffee together and would really see your personality rather than the professional look you'd expect to see in an interview for an hour.

I'd suggest you at least try and reach out, because even if it doesn't amount to anything, it'll give you contacts in the industry and when people move about you could end up with useful contacts in places you might need. All in all, it's also a good way to make acquaintances if not friends.